# Python I am making a calculator for the formula/answer of 3 different things, but 2/3 of the things display with extra characters

Tags: python-3.x

PYTHON
I am making a calculator that displays formulas and answers of a few different things after you enter time, distance, mass, etc. Velocity works fine, but Speed and Acceleration are display apostrophes, commas, and parentheses. Some of them aren't even in the editor.

Output:

```
('Speed = Distance / Time = 1m / 1s', ' = 1m/s')
('Acceleration = Force / Mass = 1N', ' / 1kg = 1.0m/s/s')
Velocity = Speed + Direction = 1m/s + Direction = 1m/s North
```

The variables in the program:

```
SpeedFormula = 'Speed = Distance / Time = ' + distanceDisplay + ' / ' + timeDisplay, ' = ' + speedDisplay
AccelerationFormula = 'Acceleration = Force / Mass = ' + forceDisplay, ' / ' + massDisplay + ' = ' + AccelerationDisplay
VelocityFormula = 'Velocity = Speed + Direction = ' + speedDisplay + " + " +  'Direction' + ' = ' + VelocityDisplay
```

Anyone know why they display differently and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
timeDisplay, ' = ' + speedDisplay
```

with

```
timeDisplay + ' = ' + speedDisplay
```

When you use comma SpeedFormula becomes a tuple, not a string.

P.S. You should probably use formatting like this:

```
distanceDisplay = 20
timeDisplay = 2
speedDisplay = 10

SpeedFormula = 'Speed = Distance / Time = %d / %d = %d' % (distanceDisplay,timeDisplay,speedDisplay)
```